# Pandas: How to replace values of Nan in column based on another column?

Tags: python, pandas

Given that, i have a dataset as below:

```
dict = {
    "A": [math.nan,math.nan,1,math.nan,2,math.nan,3,5],
    "B": np.random.randint(1,5,size=8)
}

dt = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

My favorite output is, if the in column `A` we have an Nan then multiply the value of the column `B` in the same row and replace it with `Nan`. So, given that, the below is my dataset:

```
    A  B
  NaN  1
  NaN  1
  1.0  3
  NaN  2
  2.0  3
  NaN  1
  3.0  1
  5.0  3
```

My favorite output is:

```
  A  B
  2  1
  2  1
  1  3
  4  2
  2  3
  2  1
  3  1
  5  3
```

My current solution is as below which does not work:

```
dt[pd.isna(dt["A"])]["A"] = dt[pd.isna(dt["A"])]["B"].apply( lambda x:2*x  )

print(dt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case with `fillna`

```
df.A.fillna(df.B*2, inplace=True)
df
     A  B
0  2.0  1
1  2.0  1
2  1.0  3
3  4.0  2
4  2.0  3
5  2.0  1
6  3.0  1
7  5.0  3
```

Comment: oh, this is great. will this code work if instead of  `*2` i have a random function. For instance: `df.A.fillna(myRandomFunction(df.B), inplace=True)`

Comment: @Jeff [check doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) it support `scalar, dict, Series, or DataFrame` so if your function return one of these it will be fine.